# Do mounts affect your hitbox?

Tags: heroes-of-the-storm

Do mounts affect your hitbox?

Say I have a hero who uses the Cyber Ram series of mounts, instead of something more conspicuous, like a cloud or the magic carpet. Is my hitbox affected by how large the mount is?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to [a discussion on the official Heroes of the Storm forums](https://us.battle.net/forums/en/heroes/topic/20754945768),

> Mounts don't have hitboxes, only the hero riding them does.

Related, but thought I'd add it anyway: mounts are invisible while cloaked, so the size of your shimmer for the opponent is also unaffected by your mount choice.

Comment: I did not know mounts didn't affect the size your shimmer; really glad you added that!

Comment: @BlueBarren They used to in early Beta, but they changed that because players  who played stealthed characters would end up using the smallest possible mount to minimize their shimmer. Meanwhile, players who weren't aware of the mount shimmer would pick their favorite mount, get spotted more easily and probably end up complaining about it. That's probably the same reason why mounts don't have hitboxes: you don't want your ingame balance to be affected by something meant to be purely cosmetic.